# How to pass a param to HttpInterceptor?

Tags: angular, typescript, interceptor

I am using Angular 4.3.1 and HttpClient. There is an HttpInterceptor to set some headers.

In some http get requests I need to set a different header. Is there anyway I can pass some param to this HttpInterceptor for that particular HttpRequest?

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(request.custom.param1) // how can i do this 
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'header1': 'xxxxxx'
          }
      });

    else
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'header2': 'yyyyyy'
          }
      });


    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Maybe there's a better way to handle this problem, but as a workaround you can create and pass custom `HttpParams` to request and then check them in the interceptor. For example:

```
export class CustomHttpParams extends HttpParams {
  constructor(public param1: boolean) {
   super();
  }
}
```

Using this class in http call:

```
this.http.get('https://example.com', {
  params: new CustomHttpParams(true)
})
```

And now in interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (request.params instanceof CustomHttpParams && request.params.param1) 
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'header1': 'xxxxxx'
      }
    });
  else
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'header2': 'yyyyyy'
      }
    });

  return next.handle(request);
}
```

Comment: This would pass any param all the way to the server which is not desirable.

Comment: @Amitabh, `param1` will be **not** passed to the server

Comment: Its not passing the param1 to the server. But this would only work if I don't have to pass any other param to the server.

Comment: @Amitabh, why? you can work with `CustomHttpParams` as with regular `HttpParams`. Have you tried this?

Comment: This does not work because if i have to set another http param we use the chained method and that returns HttpParam instead of CustomHttpParams

Comment: oh, I see. In order this to work `clone` method should be overridden, but it is defined as `private`

Answer (score 19):

I wrote an interceptor for handling Http error responses. I wanted to allow specific Http calls to instruct the interceptor to ignore certain response status codes, while also retaining the ability to pass params to the Http call. Here is the solution I ended up with. (Thanks, Aleksey for the initial idea in your answer).

Extend HttpParams:

```
import { HttpParams, HttpParamsOptions  } from '@angular/common/http';

// Cause the HttpErrorInterceptor to ignore certain error response status codes like this:
//
//  this.http.get<TypeHere>(`URL_HERE`, {
//    params: new InterceptorHttpParams({ statusCodesToIgnore: [400, 401] }, {
//      complete: 'false',
//      offset: '0',
//      limit: '50'
//    })
//  })

export class InterceptorHttpParams extends HttpParams {
  constructor(
    public interceptorConfig: { statusCodesToIgnore: number[] },
    params?: { [param: string]: string | string[] }
  ) {
    super({ fromObject: params } as HttpParamsOptions);
  }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    tap({
      error: (error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          const regEx = /^[4-5][0-9][0-9]$/; // 4XX and 5XX status codes

          if (regEx.test(error.status.toString())) {
              const errorMessage = this.getErrorMessageFromStatus(error.status);

              if (!this._shouldIgnoreError(req, error)) {
                console.log(`ERROR INTERCEPTOR: ${error.status}`);
                this.toastService.alert(errorMessage);
              }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  );
}

// Based on `request.params.interceptorConfig.statusCodesToIgnore`, we can see if we should ignore this error.
_shouldIgnoreError(request: HttpRequest<any>, errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (request.params instanceof InterceptorHttpParams
    && Array.isArray(request.params.interceptorConfig.statusCodesToIgnore)
    && request.params.interceptorConfig.statusCodesToIgnore.includes(errorResponse.status)) {

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer is more useful than the currently marked one as it keep the doors open to support other real parameters along with the parameter for interceptor.

Comment: On the other hand marked answer has purely aimed core problem and it's up to reader to modify his/her use-case.

Comment: @MaheshVS How can this answer be useful, or even an answer? The OP asked to conditionally set headers to **outgoing requests** while this is instructing how to conditionally ignore error codes on **incoming responses**

Comment: While this answer triggers the idea of inheritance of httpparams to add a property and do whatever is needed with it, it seems the party ends in angular 6 with the change to HTTP :( .

Comment: @AdriánPoplavsky Can you further explain what you mean? This code still works in Angular 14 for me, but as indicated by @btx below, this interceptor should be updated to leverage `HttpRequest.context` in Angular 12+.

Answer (score 8):

In Angular 12+, there's a new attribute `HttpRequest.context` designed to solve this.

> Shared and mutable context that can be used by interceptors
> https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#context

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Angular does not support passing "interceptor config/metadata" via the HttpRequest object (it has been an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18155) for quite some time).

As a possible workaround, we can define a new `MyHttpParams` class which extends Angular's `HttpParams`, adding a new `interceptorMetadata` property.

Note that `MyHttpParams` must override the `append`, `set` and `delete` methods so that they return `MyHttpParams` instead of Angular's `HttpParams`. If we don't do this, our `interceptorMetadata` will be "dropped" when those methods are invoked (e.g. if an interceptor adds some HTTP param, the next interceptors will not get the `interceptorMetadata`).

```
import {HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

export interface InterceptorMetadata {
    readonly customParam1: string;
    readonly customParam2: number;
    // etc.
}

export interface MyHttpParamsConfig {
    interceptorMetadata: Partial<InterceptorMetadata>;
    params: string | Record<string, string | string[]>; // the actual params which will be included in the real request
}

export class MyHttpParams extends HttpParams {
    public readonly interceptorMetadata: Partial<InterceptorMetadata>;

    constructor({params, interceptorMetadata}: Partial<MyHttpParamsConfig> = {}) {
        if(typeof params === 'string') {
            super({fromString: params});
        }
        else if(typeof params === 'object') {
            super({fromObject: params});
        }
        else {
            super();
        }

        this.interceptorMetadata = interceptorMetadata;
    }

    // orverrides HttpParams.append
    append(param: string, value: string): MyHttpParams {
        const updatedHttpParams = super.append(param, value);
        return new MyHttpParams({
            interceptorMetadata: this.interceptorMetadata,
            params: updatedHttpParams.toString()
        });
    }

    // orverrides HttpParams.set
    set(param: string, value: string): MyHttpParams {
        const updatedHttpParams = super.set(param, value);
        return new MyHttpParams({
            interceptorMetadata: this.interceptorMetadata,
            params: updatedHttpParams.toString()
        });
    }

    // orverrides HttpParams.delete
    delete(param: string, value?: string): MyHttpParams {
        const updatedHttpParams = super.delete(param, value);
        return new MyHttpParams({
            interceptorMetadata: this.interceptorMetadata,
            params: updatedHttpParams.toString()
        });
    }
}
```

Then for example when calling HttpClient.get() we can pass an instance of our extended MyHttpParams:

```
const myHttpParams = new MyHttpParams({
    interceptorMetadata: {
        customParam1: 'test', // this will NOT be part of the final request
    },
    params: 'someActualUrlQueryString=someValue' // this will be part of the final request
});

httpClient.get(myUrl, {params: myHttpParams})
```

Finally, in our interceptor we can use `interceptorMetadata`:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const {params} = req;
    if(params instanceof MyHttpParams) {
        if (params.interceptorMetadata && params.interceptorMetadata.customParam1 === 'test') { 
            // do something
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Thanks to [JWess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011648/jwess) for the original answer which this is based on (it was just missing the `append`, `set` and `delete` overrides)

Answer (score 2):

As @btx said there's a new attribute **HttpRequest.context** since **Angular12+** which can be used for sharing data between **HttpCliend** and **HttpInterceptor**.

Here is a **sample code** used to add the Authorization header for each secured request.

```
export const IS_ROUTE_SECURED = new HttpContextToken<boolean>(() => false);

export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const headers = {
      ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']: CONSTANTS.API_BASE_URL
    } as Record<string, string>;

    if(request.context.get(IS_ROUTE_SECURED)) {
      headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getAuthToken();
    }

    return next.handle(request.clone({ setHeaders: headers }));
  }
}

// inside a service
this.httpClient.get('/api/users', {
  context: new HttpContext().set(IS_ROUTE_SECURED, true)
}).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: HttpContext is so elegant way to pass a information to interceptor, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can use setParam option of request.

```
export class WebReqInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
stringifiedData: any;  
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
        this.stringifiedData=JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
        request = request.clone({
            setParams:{
                access_token:this.stringifiedData.access_token
            }                          
        });
        return next.handle(request);
    }
    else{
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is stumbled upon the same issue, we can pass custom params in HttpParams in new versions of angular. But we have to remember that HttpParams is an immutable object. With an immutable object, every call to params.append() returns a new object. so, we will have to re-assign the returned new object back to params as shown below,

```
 var params = new HttpParams();
 // Notice that I am re-assigning the params object
 params = params.append('showErrorMessage', 'false'); 
 return this.http.get(url, { params: params });
```

And in the interceptor, we can access the value as such

```
req.params.get('showErrorMessage')
```